# How to display OneToMany relationship in list/search view EasyAdminBundle 2x?

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

I use EasyAdminBundle 2x and Symfony 4.4. I have two entities:

`UserCase` entity:

```
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\MyReports", mappedBy="userCase")
     */
    protected $myReports;
```

And `MyReports` entity:

```
   /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\ORM\Entity\UserCase", inversedBy="myReports", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_case", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     * @Serializer\Exclude()
     */
    protected $userCase;

    /**
     * @var DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="verified_date", type="datetime", nullable = true)
     */
    protected $verifiedDate;
```

In the list view of UserCase, I would like to show the `verifiedDate` of **the latest** MyReports that UserCase relation with. Something like that:

```
easy_admin:
    entities:
        UserCase:
            class: App\ORM\Entity\UserCase
            list:
                fields:
                    - { property: 'myReports.last.verifiedDate'}
```

How could I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use`EasyAdmin` [Virtual Properties](https://symfony.com/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/2.x/book/list-search-show-configuration.html#virtual-properties):

- add `verifiedDate` property to `easy_admin` config file (instead of `'myReports.last.verifiedDate'`);
- add new public method to `UseCase` entity: `getVerifiedDate` with your logic of selecting last record with proper date;

Also: I'd recommend adding extra property to `UserCase` e.g. `verifiedDate` that will be updated instead of fetching last record for each row in grid.

Comment: Thank @Kamil, And how could I sort the UserCase list by verifiedDate in this case? The document said: "The main limitation of virtual properties is that you cannot sort listings using these fields." ?

Comment: Yes, to sort by this property you would need extra property on `UserCase` entity (stored in DB) that should be auto updated with new `MyReports` record.